# Remapping the iconize button on Mac windows

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to change the behavior of the yellow iconize button so that it hides the window (as CMD-h does) instead of iconizing it?

Using the yellow minimize button in Mac applications causes the app to disappear.  I have it set so that no extra icon is created in the dock (preference setting: 'Minimize windows into application icon').  When Alt-TAB is later used to restore the app, the window is not restored from the icon although the app itself does become active.  This behavior is for some reason different from how CMD-h works.

Alternatively, is there a one-key way to restore the window (or can I somehow create such a shortcut, preferably using Return)?  I have found that I can ctrl-F3 and then arrow to the application icon and hit return.  But that is many key strokes.  I can also ctrl-down to get the expose thing then select the iconized window and hit return. Again that is several key strokes.

Comment: You’re simply not supposed to use a Mac with the keyboard. It’s not intended for people who actually want to do real work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyboard kludge [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/26183)

Quoting:

```
When you ⌘ + ⇥ to that application, hold the ⌥ key before releasing ⌘. 
This will reopen the application, typically bringing up a minimized 
window if there are no other windows up.
```

You can in fact slide your thumb quickly off ⌘ onto ⌥ to get the effect. To be useful though you'd have to get into the habit of doing that every time unless you can remember when it will be necessary.  Unsatisfactory really...